# DNS error when using docker buildx inside local gitlab-runner

Tags: docker, dns, gitlab

I'm getting following error when trying to build an multiarch image.

`error: failed to solve: failed to do request: Head "https://registry.gitlab.mydomain.tld/v2/repo/project/blobs/sha256:24892ef5fd862876fda584afbdabfe7b1a1c8273fdcd581d6fa93232d5f8f79b": dial tcp: lookup registry.gitlab.mydomain.tld on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host`

My setup is as following: I run a custom gitlab installation that is accessable under `gitlab.mydomain.tld` and `registry.gitlab.mydomain.tld`. The dns entries can only be resolved by my local dns server running on the host. The host also runs the gitlab-runner inside a docker container like this:

```
gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:alpine
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
        TZ: Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        - ./gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner
```

DNS inside the gitlab-runner works fine. But when the `docker buildx build` command is invoked, buildx can't resolve the url.

Adding `--add-host "registry.gitlab.mydomain.tld:0.0.0.0"` also doens't do the trick.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `The dns entries can only be resolved by my local dns server running on the host.` => `lookup registry.gitlab.mydomain.tld on 8.8.8.8:53: no such host` <= the resolution is taking place on google's public dns, not on your local server.

Comment: Look for `dns` in https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-runnersdocker-section. Your local server should be the first in the list.

Comment: I believe there's an open issue regarding this here: https://github.com/moby/buildkit/issues/2404